# Using information from User Profiles Outside of SharePoint

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, web-applications, user-profile

I'm creating website that creates a page for each person in our department with their contact information. The page can then be linked to from a qr code on a business card.

What is the best way to get the information out of their SharePoint profiles?

edit: I'm not very familiar with creating stuff in Visual Studio. I'm using Ruby on Rails for the website and I've read SharePoint has REST services which would work great but I can't seem to figure out how to access the User Profile information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use Visual Studio.  You just need to be able to use a SOAP based web service from Ruby.  The documentation for the User Profile web service is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa980957(office.12).aspx

Comment: Any examples of someone doing this? Specifically SharePoint Web Services with the ruby Savon gem, I can't seem to get it working from the directions on the Savon website.

Comment: Not much of a Ruby or Savon user myself but make sure that you nail down authentication and use some sort of proxy tool to view the wire between Ruby and SharePoint.  A lot of SharePoint implementations use NTLM as their web authentication technique and I know that doesn't always work right OOTB for some languages that aren't explicitly targeting Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SharePoint UserProfile WebService to achieve this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms494053.aspx

Or, if you need something more specific, you could create your own WebService which access's the UserProfile API like this -

```
 using (var site = new SPSite("http://yourserver"))
    {
        var userProfileManager = 
            new UserProfileManager(SPServiceContext.GetContext(site));

        var userProfile =
            userProfileManager.GetUserProfile("domain\accountName");

        //iterate the userprofile properties
        foreach (UserProfileValueCollection prop in userProfile)
            Console.WriteLine(prop.Value);
    }
```